Get list of blobs from Azure Storage
Trying to convert this old Framework 4.6 code to .Net 8.
I've upgrade the project, but having an issue with container.Listblobs(..)
Here's the original framework code


using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AzureContentTypeUpdater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountName"])
                    || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountKey"])
                    || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureContainerName"])
                    || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureSiteName"]))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Please Verify configuration, some properties are missing.");
                }
                StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(
                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountName"],
                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountKey"]);
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
                var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureContainerName"]);
                //filter list of all files 
                var list = container.ListBlobs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureSiteName"], true)
                            .OfType<CloudBlob>()
                            .Where(x => x.Uri.ToString().Contains(".pdf"));

                foreach (var x in list)
                {
                    if (x.Properties.ContentType == "application/octet-stream")
                        x.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    x.SetProperties();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("All Files Were Processed Successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not process files. Exception : {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}



And now after installing the Microsoft.WindowsAzure NuGet packages into my .Net 8 project, here's my new code.
The line var list = container.ListBlobs is the problem at the moment.


using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AzureContentTypeUpdater
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountName"])
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountKey"])
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureContainerName"])
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureSiteName"]))
            {
                throw new Exception("Please Verify configuration, some properties are missing.");
            }


            StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(
                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountName"],
                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAccountKey"]);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureContainerName"]);

            //filter list of all files
            var list = container.ListBlobs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureSiteName"], true)
                        .OfType<CloudBlob>()
                        .Where(x => x.Uri.ToString().Contains(".pdf"));

            foreach (var x in list)
            {
                if (x.Properties.ContentType == "application/octet-stream")
                    x.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                x.SetProperties();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("All Files Were Processed Successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Could not process files. Exception : {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
}



But I'm struggling with the container.ListBlobs section:

It appears that I've installed the correct packages

Does this answer your question? How to get a list of all the blobs in a container in Azure?

I am pretty sure that the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.* namespaces refer to the older libraries that target netstandard 1.3 and netframework 4.5.  You should be looking at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.* instead.  From what I can gather Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob is deprecated, and we should be using Azure.Storage.Blobs.

I will be checking both of these suggestions today, as I had a hunch that I was using the wrong namespaces.

Is the below approach worked for you?


Get list of blobs from Azure Storage

According to this MS-Document,
The ListBlobs method is not available in the latest version of the Azure Storage client library for .NET.
Instead, you can use the GetBlobs orGetBlobsAsync method of the BlobContainerClient class to list blobs in a container.
Code:
Here is the sample code to list the pdf files only from azure blob storage using Azure.Storage.Blobs=12.20.0 package with net8.0.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListPdfBlobs
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "xxxxxx";
            string containerName = "test";

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            await foreach (var blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                if (blob.Name.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
UnsignedDocument.pdf
file_8222193f-2da6-428f-9b9b-167c2ffb0816.pdf


Project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.20.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
